# Reusing simple form i18n labels for #show under Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n

Simple Form has its own I18n namespace e.g en.simple_form.labels. We can define translations for labels, placeholders and hints here and they get rendered on the form (e.g #edit, #new)

However, on #show, which is technically not a form, when translating labels for attributes we fall back to translations defined in en.helpers, or en.activerecord.attributes.

Most of the time, the labels are the same and there's this sense of unnecessary duplication.

I'm new to Rails, so I'm wondering what's the normal way of doing things.

1. Rewire translations on en.helpers to use the ones in Simple Form. How?
2. Render #show using simple_form_for, even though it's not really something that we'd submit.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Should have looked up the available configuration options in

Here's one to simply rewire the translations under a different namespace.

```
config.i18n_scope = 'simple_form'
```

Just change it to whatever namespace you wish to consolidate the translations in.